# Can't open worlds on latest update of Minecraft PE (0.16.0)

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

We have just updated to minecraft PE 0.16 from 0.15 and can no longer open any of the worlds created in earlier versions.  Can anyone advise the best thing to do?  My son has spent many months creating these worlds, and it will be a big disappointment to lose them!  They all opened fine on 0.15.0.  Thanks

Comment: Which device are you using? Android, IOS or what?

Answer (score -1):

My son is having the same dilemma. After searching the internet I have found a YouTube video posted with lots of comments the same from iOS users. The update 0.16.0 does not seem to be loading for everybody. The only answer I can find is: we need to wait for a new update of this 'major bug issue'. That's what ivevtold my son... For now... I'll keep checking. I'm not very techy.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer to this question, but it would be of great help to everybody reading this if you could link the YouTube video in question. Thanks!